# Make PHP to search everything

Tags: php, mysql, search

I was wondering how I would search more tables in my search database to include city and search. City and search is already in my database all I need to do is search them, but i don't know how.

This is what i have so far:

```
//explode out search term
$search_exploded = explode(" ",$search);

foreach($search_exploded as $search_each) {

//construct query
$x++;
if ($x==1)
    $construct .= " keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
else
    $construct .= " OR keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
}
```

Comment: Which error? You should show it.

Comment: Not an error like a parse error, but it would only search the keywords. I just want to include the city and state in the search since they're in the same table

Comment: please copy/paste the error you are getting.

Comment: Why don't you just add it to the SQL query then? What's your problem?

Comment: I did. $construct .=" keywords, city, state LIKE '%$search_each%'"; but that didnt work. It only searched for keywords

Comment: @contagious there was no error it just wouldnt work. ill edit the post

Comment: You need to use OR to join the multiple columns. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code to:

```
foreach($search_exploded as $search_each) {
    //construct query
    $x++;

    if ($x==1)
        $construct .= " keywords LIKE 
            '%$search_each%' OR city LIKE '%$search_each%' or state LIKE 
            '%search_each%'";
    else
        $construct .= " OR keywords LIKE 
            '%$search_each%' OR city LIKE 
            '%$search_each%' or state LIKE '%search_each%'";
}
```

Comment: Invalid  argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: That is a PHP error. Check your code. I helped you with your MySQL part. The only thing I did was to copy your own code and modify it. Your own code should have given the same error.